# how to Check spelling of a regional language?

Tags: c#, winforms, indic

I have winform application where user can input text in hindi language by copy paste. I want to have a validation that check the inputted text is a proper word.
from google i comes to know that by using **ILIT** we can  input regional language. By using the same can I check spell also if yes then how?

Comment: This might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4572/Using-Word-s-spellchecker-in-C

Comment: Ya got that link but i want in regional language

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NHuspell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56332/NHunspellTextBoxExtender-A-Spellchecking-IExtender). It supports multiple language dictionaries. Pretty good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56332/NHunspellTextBoxExtender-A-Spellchecking-IExtender).